# How to add a WebPart in List Display form using PowerShell

Tags: 2010, list, custom-form, list-form, list-form-web-part

I would like to add a standard list view Webpart inside of another list form page. I'm on SharePoint 2010 and it is really easy to perform by using the UI. How to do the same by with PowerShell ? I've been visited several pages on internet but the procedures did not worked for me.

It will be great if I could do the same without removing the current list display form. So far I've been able to do this.

```
$web = get-spweb "http://www.questionstackexchange.fr/subsite";
$list = $web.lists["MyLittleList"];
$files = $list.rootfolder.files;

$form = $list.RootFolder.files | ?{$_.url -match "dispform.aspx"};
$form.delete();
$list.update();

$dispformurl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Dispform.aspx";
$dispform = $files.add($dispformurl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::FormPage);
$wpm = $dispform.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);
$lfw = new-object ([Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormwebpart]);
$lfw2 = new-object ([Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart]); 
$ilist = [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.IListWebPart]($lfw);
$ilist2 = [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.IListWebPart]($lfw2);
$ilist.ListId = $list.id;
$ilist2.ListId = "B4A7D0D0-221D-492C-B6E6-A5D758EDD3F2";
$ilist.PageType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE]::PAGE_DISPLAYFORM;
$ilist2.PageType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE]::PAGE_DISPLAYFORM;
$wpm.AddWebPart($lfw, "Main", 1) ;
$wpm.AddWebPart($lfw2, "Header", 1) ;
$list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl = $dispformurl;
$list.update();
```

I get the web part maintenance page.

[Source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yashgoel-msft/2013/08/30/recreating-default-display-edit-and-new-forms-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/)

Comment: Is above code working?

Comment: It's not. But It was closer. Actually I replaced the part *PAGE_DISPLAYFORM* by *PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW* from the *ilist2.PageType* and it's working now but I dont know how to do it without removing the current display form before inserting the new view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$web = get-spweb "http://SharePointSite";
$list = $web.lists["MyList"];
$wpPage = $list.RootFolder.files | ?{$_.url -match "dispform.aspx"};

$wpm = $wpPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);
$webpart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart
$webpart.ListId = "{C5B492BF-8869-4459-823D-21E43F10BAB9}"
$wpm.AddWebPart($webpart,"",0)
```

Comment: Great. Welcome :)